# file upload using dojo.io.frame.send doesn't work in IE the first time

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm trying to do an ajax file upload using dojo.io.frame.send(). It works with FF and chrome without any issues but not in IE 8 (not sure about other versions). The code is pasted below:

```
function submitForm()
{       
dojo.require("dojo.io.iframe");
dojo.io.iframe.send({
    url : "/uploadfile.do",
    form : "myForm",
    method: "POST",     
    handleAs: 'text',
    load : function(response, ioArgs) 
    {
        return response;
    },
    error : function(response, ioArgs) {
        return response;
    }
}); 
return false;
}
```

I searched on the web and found this:
http://groups.google.com/group/dojo-interest/browse_thread/thread/17dace02652bcec3

which prompted me to add the following snippet after dojo.require() line in the above code:

```
if ((dojo.isSafari || dojo.isIE) && dojo.io.iframe["_frame"])
{
    dojo.destroy(dojo.io.iframe['_frame']);
    var frameName = dojo.io.iframe._iframeName;
    dojo.io.iframe["_frame"] = window[frameName] = null;
    if (window.frames)
        window.frames[frameName] = null;
}
```

With this it doesn't work in IE the first time but works when I click on the upload button the second time.

Additional info: My form tag in HTML has method="post" parameter.

Comment: what version of Dojo are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work in IE 8 by explicitly setting the http response content type to "text/html" at the server. Weird that IE 9, FF and Chrome provide that flexibility but IE is much stricter.